# On initialising PWM with registers on my Due, why does unrelated duty cycle input influence my output?

Tags: pwm, arduino-due

I am finding that setting duty cycle on PWM channels 4 or 5 has an influence on whether channel 6 generates output. The following is a design of experiments view of my tests and results, where the outputs are measured on pins associated with PWM channels, high or low. PWM channels 4 and 7 appear not to have a high channel. The configuration allows for 2100 ticks per cycle, so 1050 is 50% and 1575 is 75%.

Why does duty cycle on PWM channels 4 or 5 affect the output of channel 6?

Why does setting a duty on channels 4 or 5 not yield output on those channels?

```
       Channels included in     Channels included in    Channels given duty cycle                     Measuered PWM Output on Pins/channels
Test   ASBR, PDR                CMR, CPRD               CDTYUPD                                       D6 (PWML7)    D7 (PWML6)    D8 (PWML5)    D9 (PWML4)    D44 (PWMH5)    D45 (PWMH6)
------|------------------------|-----------------------|--------------------------------------------||-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|--------------|-----------
A      C24, C23, C22, C21       4, 5, 6, 7                       4: 1050, 5: 1050, 6: 1050, 7: 1575   75%           50%           0%            0%            0%             0%            
B      C24, C23                 4, 5, 6, 7                       4: 1050, 5: 1050, 6: 1050, 7: 1575   75%           50%           0%            0%            0%             0%            
C      C24, C23, C22, C21             6, 7                       4: 1050, 5: 1050, 6: 1050, 7: 1575   75%           50%           0%            0%            0%             0%            
D      C24, C23                       6, 7                       4: 1050, 5: 1050, 6: 1050, 7: 1575   75%           50%           0%            0%            0%             0%            
E      C24, C23, C22, C21       4, 5, 6, 7                                         6: 1050, 7: 1575   75%           0%            0%            0%            0%             0%            
F      C24, C23                 4, 5, 6, 7                                         6: 1050, 7: 1575   75%           0%            0%            0%            0%             0%            
G      C24, C23, C22, C21             6, 7                                         6: 1050, 7: 1575   75%           0%            0%            0%            0%             0%            
H      C24, C23                       6, 7                                         6: 1050, 7: 1575   75%           0%            0%            0%            0%             0%            
I      C24, C23                       6, 7                       4: 1050,          6: 1050, 7: 1575   75%           50%           0%            0%            0%             0%            
J      C24, C23                       6, 7                                5: 1050, 6: 1050, 7: 1575   75%           50%           0%            0%            0%             0%            
K      C24, C23                       6, 7              3: 1050,                   6: 1050, 7: 1575   75%           0%            0%            0%            0%             0%
```

**Further Information:**

Output to PWM7 is not necessary, so have simplified problem. Also the duty value set on channels 4 or 5 can be anything, so long as it is set.

```
void O_() {
  REG_PMC_PCER1 |= PMC_PCER1_PID36;                                               
  REG_PIOC_ABSR |= PIO_ABSR_P23;
  REG_PIOC_PDR |= PIO_PDR_P23;          
  REG_PWM_CLK = PWM_CLK_PREA(0) | PWM_CLK_DIVA(1);
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[6].PWM_CMR =  PWM_CMR_CPRE_CLKA;                 
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[6].PWM_CPRD = 2100;  
  REG_PWM_ENA = PWM_ENA_CHID6;  
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[4].PWM_CDTYUPD = 0; // Eliminating this line prevents output on channel 6 for some reason
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[6].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
}
```

Original DOE source code:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  L_();
}

void A_() {
  REG_PMC_PCER1 |= PMC_PCER1_PID36;                                               
  REG_PIOC_ABSR |= PIO_ABSR_P24 | PIO_ABSR_P23 | PIO_ABSR_P22 | PIO_ABSR_P21;
  REG_PIOC_PDR |= PIO_PDR_P24 | PIO_PDR_P23 | PIO_PDR_P22 | PIO_PDR_P21;          
  REG_PWM_CLK = PWM_CLK_PREA(0) | PWM_CLK_DIVA(1);
  for (uint8_t i = 4; i < PWMCH_NUM_NUMBER; i++)                    
  {
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CMR =  PWM_CMR_CPRE_CLKA;                 
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CPRD = 2100;                              
  }
  REG_PWM_ENA = PWM_ENA_CHID7 | PWM_ENA_CHID6;
  
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[4].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[5].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[6].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[7].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1575;
}

void B_() {
  REG_PMC_PCER1 |= PMC_PCER1_PID36;                                               
  REG_PIOC_ABSR |= PIO_ABSR_P24 | PIO_ABSR_P23;
  REG_PIOC_PDR |= PIO_PDR_P24 | PIO_PDR_P23;          
  REG_PWM_CLK = PWM_CLK_PREA(0) | PWM_CLK_DIVA(1);
  for (uint8_t i = 4; i < PWMCH_NUM_NUMBER; i++)                    
  {
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CMR =  PWM_CMR_CPRE_CLKA;                 
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CPRD = 2100;                              
  }
  REG_PWM_ENA = PWM_ENA_CHID7 | PWM_ENA_CHID6;
  
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[4].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[5].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[6].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[7].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1575;
}

void C_() {
  REG_PMC_PCER1 |= PMC_PCER1_PID36;                                               
  REG_PIOC_ABSR |= PIO_ABSR_P24 | PIO_ABSR_P23 | PIO_ABSR_P22 | PIO_ABSR_P21;
  REG_PIOC_PDR |= PIO_PDR_P24 | PIO_PDR_P23 | PIO_PDR_P22 | PIO_PDR_P21;          
  REG_PWM_CLK = PWM_CLK_PREA(0) | PWM_CLK_DIVA(1);
  for (uint8_t i = 6; i < PWMCH_NUM_NUMBER; i++)                    
  {
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CMR =  PWM_CMR_CPRE_CLKA;                 
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CPRD = 2100;                              
  }
  REG_PWM_ENA = PWM_ENA_CHID7 | PWM_ENA_CHID6;
  
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[4].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[5].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[6].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[7].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1575;
}

void D_() {
  REG_PMC_PCER1 |= PMC_PCER1_PID36;                                               
  REG_PIOC_ABSR |= PIO_ABSR_P24 | PIO_ABSR_P23;
  REG_PIOC_PDR |= PIO_PDR_P24 | PIO_PDR_P23;          
  REG_PWM_CLK = PWM_CLK_PREA(0) | PWM_CLK_DIVA(1);
  for (uint8_t i = 6; i < PWMCH_NUM_NUMBER; i++)                    
  {
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CMR =  PWM_CMR_CPRE_CLKA;                 
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CPRD = 2100;                              
  }
  REG_PWM_ENA = PWM_ENA_CHID7 | PWM_ENA_CHID6;
  
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[4].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[5].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[6].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[7].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1575;
}

void E_() {
  REG_PMC_PCER1 |= PMC_PCER1_PID36;                                               
  REG_PIOC_ABSR |= PIO_ABSR_P24 | PIO_ABSR_P23 | PIO_ABSR_P22 | PIO_ABSR_P21;
  REG_PIOC_PDR |= PIO_PDR_P24 | PIO_PDR_P23 | PIO_PDR_P22 | PIO_PDR_P21;          
  REG_PWM_CLK = PWM_CLK_PREA(0) | PWM_CLK_DIVA(1);
  for (uint8_t i = 4; i < PWMCH_NUM_NUMBER; i++)                    
  {
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CMR =  PWM_CMR_CPRE_CLKA;                 
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CPRD = 2100;                              
  }
  REG_PWM_ENA = PWM_ENA_CHID7 | PWM_ENA_CHID6;
  
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[6].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[7].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1575;
}

void F_() {
  REG_PMC_PCER1 |= PMC_PCER1_PID36;                                               
  REG_PIOC_ABSR |= PIO_ABSR_P24 | PIO_ABSR_P23;
  REG_PIOC_PDR |= PIO_PDR_P24 | PIO_PDR_P23;          
  REG_PWM_CLK = PWM_CLK_PREA(0) | PWM_CLK_DIVA(1);
  for (uint8_t i = 4; i < PWMCH_NUM_NUMBER; i++)                    
  {
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CMR =  PWM_CMR_CPRE_CLKA;                 
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CPRD = 2100;                              
  }
  REG_PWM_ENA = PWM_ENA_CHID7 | PWM_ENA_CHID6;
  
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[6].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[7].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1575;
}

void G_() {
  REG_PMC_PCER1 |= PMC_PCER1_PID36;                                               
  REG_PIOC_ABSR |= PIO_ABSR_P24 | PIO_ABSR_P23 | PIO_ABSR_P22 | PIO_ABSR_P21;
  REG_PIOC_PDR |= PIO_PDR_P24 | PIO_PDR_P23 | PIO_PDR_P22 | PIO_PDR_P21;          
  REG_PWM_CLK = PWM_CLK_PREA(0) | PWM_CLK_DIVA(1);
  for (uint8_t i = 6; i < PWMCH_NUM_NUMBER; i++)                    
  {
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CMR =  PWM_CMR_CPRE_CLKA;                 
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CPRD = 2100;                              
  }
  REG_PWM_ENA = PWM_ENA_CHID7 | PWM_ENA_CHID6;
  
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[6].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[7].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1575;
}

void H_() {
  REG_PMC_PCER1 |= PMC_PCER1_PID36;                                               
  REG_PIOC_ABSR |= PIO_ABSR_P24 | PIO_ABSR_P23;
  REG_PIOC_PDR |= PIO_PDR_P24 | PIO_PDR_P23;          
  REG_PWM_CLK = PWM_CLK_PREA(0) | PWM_CLK_DIVA(1);
  for (uint8_t i = 6; i < PWMCH_NUM_NUMBER; i++)                    
  {
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CMR =  PWM_CMR_CPRE_CLKA;                 
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CPRD = 2100;                              
  }
  REG_PWM_ENA = PWM_ENA_CHID7 | PWM_ENA_CHID6;
  
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[6].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[7].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1575;
}

void I_() {
  REG_PMC_PCER1 |= PMC_PCER1_PID36;                                               
  REG_PIOC_ABSR |= PIO_ABSR_P24 | PIO_ABSR_P23;
  REG_PIOC_PDR |= PIO_PDR_P24 | PIO_PDR_P23;          
  REG_PWM_CLK = PWM_CLK_PREA(0) | PWM_CLK_DIVA(1);
  for (uint8_t i = 6; i < PWMCH_NUM_NUMBER; i++)                    
  {
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CMR =  PWM_CMR_CPRE_CLKA;                 
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CPRD = 2100;                              
  }
  REG_PWM_ENA = PWM_ENA_CHID7 | PWM_ENA_CHID6;
  
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[4].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[6].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[7].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1575;
}

void J_() {
  REG_PMC_PCER1 |= PMC_PCER1_PID36;                                               
  REG_PIOC_ABSR |= PIO_ABSR_P24 | PIO_ABSR_P23;
  REG_PIOC_PDR |= PIO_PDR_P24 | PIO_PDR_P23;          
  REG_PWM_CLK = PWM_CLK_PREA(0) | PWM_CLK_DIVA(1);
  for (uint8_t i = 6; i < PWMCH_NUM_NUMBER; i++)                    
  {
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CMR =  PWM_CMR_CPRE_CLKA;                 
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CPRD = 2100;                              
  }
  REG_PWM_ENA = PWM_ENA_CHID7 | PWM_ENA_CHID6;
  
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[5].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[6].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[7].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1575;
}

void K_() {
  REG_PMC_PCER1 |= PMC_PCER1_PID36;                                               
  REG_PIOC_ABSR |= PIO_ABSR_P24 | PIO_ABSR_P23;
  REG_PIOC_PDR |= PIO_PDR_P24 | PIO_PDR_P23;          
  REG_PWM_CLK = PWM_CLK_PREA(0) | PWM_CLK_DIVA(1);
  for (uint8_t i = 6; i < PWMCH_NUM_NUMBER; i++)                    
  {
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CMR =  PWM_CMR_CPRE_CLKA;                 
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CPRD = 2100;                              
  }
  REG_PWM_ENA = PWM_ENA_CHID7 | PWM_ENA_CHID6;
  
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[3].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[6].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[7].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1575;
}

void L_() {
  REG_PMC_PCER1 |= PMC_PCER1_PID36;                                               
  REG_PIOC_ABSR |= PIO_ABSR_P24 | PIO_ABSR_P23 | PIO_ABSR_P22 | PIO_ABSR_P21;
  REG_PIOC_PDR |= PIO_PDR_P24 | PIO_PDR_P23 | PIO_PDR_P22 | PIO_PDR_P21;          
  REG_PWM_CLK = PWM_CLK_PREA(0) | PWM_CLK_DIVA(1);
  for (uint8_t i = 4; i < PWMCH_NUM_NUMBER; i++)                    
  {
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CMR =  PWM_CMR_CPRE_CLKA;                 
    PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[i].PWM_CPRD = 2100;                              
  }
  REG_PWM_ENA = PWM_ENA_CHID7 | PWM_ENA_CHID6;
  
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[4].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[5].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[6].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1050;
  PWM->PWM_CH_NUM[7].PWM_CDTYUPD = 1575;
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```